# Xampp 1.8.1: Apache cannot start in port 8080, which is being used by tomcat 7

Tags: apache, tomcat, xampp

I am using XAMPP1.8.1 but while starting it, the apache service is not starting because of port 8080 being used by Tomcat 7,

when used:  netstat -aon | findstr "8080" to find the process it showed **Apache Tomcat Tomcat7 is using 8080.**

for last 1 month the apache was working fine.

The error shown in XAMPP control panel is :

```
4:20:14 PM  [main]  Initializing Modules

4:20:14 PM  [Apache]    **Problem detected!**

4:20:14 PM  [Apache]    **Port 80 in use by "system"!**

4:20:14 PM  [Apache]    **Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!**

4:20:14 PM  [Apache]    **You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application**

4:20:14 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache to listen on a different port

4:20:14 PM  [mysql]     XAMPP MySQL Service is already running on port 3306

4:20:14 PM  [filezilla] XAMPP FileZilla FTP Server Service is already running on port 21

4:20:14 PM  [filezilla] XAMPP FileZilla FTP Server Service is already running on port 14147

4:20:14 PM  [Tomcat]    XAMPP Tomcat Service is already running on port 8005

4:20:14 PM  [Tomcat]    **XAMPP Tomcat Service is already running on port 8080**

4:20:14 PM  [Tomcat]    XAMPP Tomcat Service is already running on port 8009
```

Comment: so you already knew the problem, and root cause, then you shiuld be fine to fix it. Check tomcat7 setting.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options over here.
1.You probably need to kill the process which is using the 8080 port[apache tomcat]if you want 8080 port only.
2.Assign a new port address to XAMPP server.

Comment: what are the port numbers that can be used instead of 8080 and how can   I change them, as I read in an another post regarding this issue where the port 80 was changed to 8080 in " httpd.conf " file, but that also didn't worked.

Comment: After changing,did you restart the service? or in the worst case you can kill the process which is using 8080.This information you can receive from netstat

Comment: yes sir, first i restarted the service, when it didn't worked i even restarted the system.

Comment: Try killing the process which is using the 8080 port.Do you have any SNMP monitors on your system?

Comment: no i don't have any SNMP monitor, while trying to stop the process from task manager, access denied error pops out.

Comment: I guess you do not have required permissions to kill/stop the process.Are you an administrator?If not try logging in as a administrator and then try killing the process.You can also end the process from the task manager/use netstat utility for killing the process.

Comment: i am logged-in as administrator only.

Comment: Execute "FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :8080') DO @ECHO TaskKill.exe /PID %%P" from command prompt

Comment: FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^|
 findstr :8080') DO TaskKill.exe /PID %P /T /F.I gave you the .BAT command.

Comment: it killed the process and when tried to start apache it failed, and while restarting the xampp neither apache nor tomcat started had to start tomcat manually.

Answer (score 0):

stop the tomcat7 and try to restart the apache server, sometimes system services like skype may also use the same port number. disable all other programs first and run the apache.

Comment: I have tried restarting tomcat7 but nothing happened, i even tried starting apache when tomcat7 was shutdown even then also it didn't started, and i dont have skype installed.

Comment: type http://localhost in your browser, if you have seen the home page then apache is already running.