# Error in configuring tomcat in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, apache, tomcat, xampp

I have Windows 7 installed on my PC.I have downloaded XAMPP server and installed it with it's default options. However, I noticed that Tomcat does not work (while MySQL, Apache does work!). I am trying to configure Tomcat in XAMPP but getting the error below.

> 11:47:40 AM  [Tomcat]  Problem detected!
>   11:47:40 AM  [Tomcat]  Port 8080 in use by "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN\tnslsnr.exe"!
>   11:47:40 AM  [Tomcat]  Tomcat WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
>   11:47:40 AM  [Tomcat]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
>   11:47:40 AM  [Tomcat]  or reconfigure Tomcat and the Control Panel to listen on a different port .

How can I reconfigure Tomcat and the control panel to listen on a diffrent port ?

Comment: You See This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477400/xampp-1-8-1-apache-cannot-start-in-port-8080-which-is-being-used-by-tomcat-7). I hope any help you.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is self explanatory that Tomcat by default listening on prot 8080 but presently port 8080 is used by tnslsnr.exe

Go to $T0MCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml and change `<Connector port="8080"` to any port that you want for example `<Connector port="7070"` and restart tomcat

Comment: @Moshiur please vote up and mark answer if this helped you in any case. This pleased me to go a head and work more in this community

Answer (score 0):

goto  config< service and port settings  and change the port according to you server.xml file
here we change 8080 into 7070 the we change and click ok !!!!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK4gw.png)